# Android app shutting if form blank - Need a validation form

Tags: android, forms, validation, validating, validating-event

I have a app for convert km/h for mph.
If the form is blank and press button convert, the app simply closes.
I understand that i need a function thats validade if the form is blank and show a message informating users that form cannot be blank but i cannot found a code for my problem.

My onClick code is:

```
        buttonConverter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            double Value1 = Double.valueOf(txtKmhUser.getText().toString());
            double Value2 = Value1 / 1.60;
            Result.setText(String.valueOf(Value2));

        }


    });
```

Comment: You need to check if the EditText is empty. Because **"" != 0**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your app is crashing is because Double.valueOf("") throws a number format exception.  So you need to validate your form ahead of processing or use a try/catch for the exception.

```
buttonConverter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(txtQuilometros.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
             double Value1 = Double.valueOf(txtQuilometros.getText().toString());
             double Value2 = Value1 / 1.60;
             Result.setText(String.valueOf(Value2));
         } else {
          txtQuilometros.setError("Please enter a value");
    }
});
```

Comment: Very thank you you Adam W. I understand "if" logic and error thats make my app closes in this case with your help, and try one time. An alert appears in the form and app stops simply close. Later i mix your setError command with help of Marcus and i use Toast message. The app gets perfect!

Sorry my bad english

Comment: You should accept one of the answers. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can show a toast, if the `EditText` is empty.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String yourString = txtKmhUser.getText().toString();
        if(!yourString.equals("")){
            double Value1 = Double.valueOf(yourString);
            double Value2 = Value1 / 1.60;
            Result.setText(String.valueOf(Value2));
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Form can not be blank", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very thank you Marcus. I used your toast method mixed with Adam W answer and i got 2 alerts for user. As a matter of fact a short alert and a form focus.

Sorry my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Just do validation before converting

```
  buttonConverter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String str=txtQuilometros.getText().toString();
        if(str.length()>0)
        {
             double Value1 = Double.valueOf(str);
             double Value2 = Value1 / 1.60;
             Result.setText(String.valueOf(Value2));
         }

    }


});
```

Comment: forgot the change that knew it but forgot ... which change that.. Thanks for the reminder

Comment: To quote the author: "show a message informating users that form cannot be blank"

Answer (score 0):

Check your edit text has value null before converting it

```
if(!value1.equals(null))
```